# How to skip some files while committing in GitHub?

Tags: github, repository, skip

I have some configuration files in my solution. For development purpose I've done some configuration changes in those files. But i don't want those files to be get committed / pushed in my develop branch in GitHub repository. Is there any way I can add file names which I want to skip at the time of commit and push?

Comment: Do you mean `.gitignore` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply can mark it as to ignore local changes (not with `.gitignore` since it is already tracked), using [`git update-index --assume-unchanged`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index)

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged -- my-config-file
```

(You also have `git update-index --skip-worktree`: see the [difference here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23806990/6309))

A `git pull` would reset that flag.
To remove said flag manually: `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged -- my-config-file`.